# Retry ImagePullBackOff

Tags: kubernetes

I have a `Job` that should not be retried under no circumstances except when the pod fails to pull the container image. That happens because the network is not stable so the pod fails to pull the image randomly.

I have looked at [pod-failure-policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/#pod-failure-policy) and tried the following but it did not work.

```
  podFailurePolicy:
    rules:
    - action: Ignore
      onPodConditions:
      - type: ImagePullBackOff
```

Is there something I could do?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your ask correctly, you would like the job to only attempt to retry during `ImagePullBackOff` events and otherwise not attempt to retry.

From investigating the output of `kubectl explain job.spec.podFailurePolicy` I see that `rules` have the following behavior:

```
FIELDS:
  rules <[]PodFailurePolicyRule> -required-
    A list of pod failure policy rules. The rules are evaluated in order. Once a
    rule matches a Pod failure, the remaining of the rules are ignored. When no
    rule matches the Pod failure, the default handling applies - the counter of
    pod failures is incremented and it is checked against the backoffLimit. At
    most 20 elements are allowed.
```

Since it appears you only specify one rule, the default behavior of incrementing the `backoffLimit` occurs. You need to add more rules following your `Ignore` of `ImagePullBackOff` explicitly specifying the behavior you desire.